# Share Google Drive file to non Google account without notifying the recipient

Tags: google-drive-api

When sharing files using [create permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) of the Google Drive API v3, you can disable notifications from being sent to the recipient by setting the optional query parameter **sendNotificationEmail** to false.

However, this throws an error when sharing files with non-Google accounts. Currently, I use a try and except clause to handle the error then retry with the parameter set to true.

**Is there really no way of sharing a Google Drive file without notifying the recipient (when they do not have a Google account)?**

For context, my application shares the file and emails the user a link to the file amongst other things (so I don't need a separate notification sent by Google).

Comment: Try and check the Drive settings for **Access Checker**. You can share a file and Google can check that the recipients have access. These includes non-Google accounts. For more info, follow the link [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7492096?hl=en).

Comment: sorry @jess is this available to use via the API? I don't see it. How would you recommend this is implemented to check via the API before the file is shared?